# Android CameraPreview doesn't work

Tags: android, camera, preview

I'm trying to use a Camera-Preview  in Android but it doesn't work.

I took this code from a tutorial,so it has been working for some guys.

I do use:

That's my Activity-Class:

```
package mein.test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class CameraDemo extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";
Camera camera;
Preview preview;
Button buttonClick;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    preview = new Preview(this);
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);

    buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
    buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,
                    jpegCallback);
        }
    });

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
 }

ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
    }
};

/** Handles data for raw picture */
PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
    }
};

/** Handles data for jpeg picture */
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            // write to local sandbox file system
            // outStream =
            // CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg",
            // System.currentTimeMillis()), 0);
            // Or write to sdcard
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                    "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          }
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
    }
};}
```

That's the PreviewClass

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private static final String TAG = "Preview";
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    public Camera camera;
    Preview(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw.
    camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                            "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: "
                            + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Preview.this.invalidate();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
    // important to release it when the activity is paused.
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera = null;
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    Paint p = new Paint(Color.RED);
    Log.d(TAG, "draw");
    canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth() / 2,
            canvas.getHeight() / 2, p);
}}
```

and this is the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout">
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Camera Demo"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
    android:text="Click" android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="mein.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Preview" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>


</manifest>
```

Error-Log:

```
11-02 01:11:25.222: E/SecCamera(76): initCamera: m_cam_fd(15), m_jpeg_fd(0)
11-02 01:12:52.070: E/SecCamera(76): initCamera: m_cam_fd(15), m_jpeg_fd(0)
11-02 01:12:52.082: E/SecCamera(76): initCamera: m_cam_fd2(21)
11-02 01:12:52.128: E/CameraHardwareSec(76): virtual android::status_t android::CameraHardwareSec::setParameters(const android::CameraParameters&): Invalid preview size(480x604)
11-02 01:12:52.136: D/AndroidRuntime(6448): Shutting down VM
11-02 01:12:52.136: W/dalvikvm(6448): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:914)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at mein.test.Preview.surfaceChanged(Preview.java:78)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:549)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:348)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-02 01:12:52.140: E/AndroidRuntime(6448):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

You can see this line in the log:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mein.test.CameraPreview in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/mein.test-2.apk]`

You didn't post the full code (I don't see the `package` directive), but do you have a class `CameraPreview` in the package `mein.test` somewhere?

Comment: i fixed this now, but I still get the same Error-Log  :

Comment: Ok guys I solved the problem :)
The Preview-Size was wrong ... 

Thank you very much for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, you have the following code:

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".CameraPreview" >
...
```

It's looking for a class called CameraPreview, but that does not exist in your project. Your activity is called CameraDemo. Fix the discrepancy.

Comment: ok i fixed this, but the Log still says :  11-02 00:38:22.003: E/AndroidRuntime(5911): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{mein.test/mein.test.Preview}: java.lang.InstantiationException: mein.test.Preview
11-02 00:38:22.003: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)

Comment: Edit your question to provide the full log.

Comment: Ok guys I solved the problem :)
The Preview-Size was wrong ... 

Thank you very much for your help !!